# Finite algebras with finitely many automorphisms

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, automorphism-groups

Let $B'/B$ be a finite locally free algebra. Locally in $B$, there is an isomorphism of $B$-modules $B'\simeq B^{\oplus n}$. When is the automorphism group of $B'/B$ finite? When is it unramified? Is there a locus in $B$ where the fibers of $B'/B$ have these properties?

I feel like it should be finite most of the time, e.g. for Galois field extensions. But the group is infinite for ramified extensions, like the dual numbers $k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$ over an infinite field $k$. If there is an element $\theta \in B'$ that generates it as an algebra $B'= B[\theta]$, it seems that $\theta$ must map to another root of the equation under automorphisms, but the dual numbers fit this description also. There are other examples besides the dual numbers, but must they all involve some non-reducedness of the rings?

Motivation: There is a moduli space $\frak A$ due to Bjorn Poonen of finite locally free algebras. A morphism $Spec B \to \frak A$ is the same as a finite locally free algebra extension $B'/B$. Define the moduli space of stable algebras $\bar{\frak A} \subseteq \frak A$ as the maximal substack of DM type: this means algebras with unramified automorphism group, or almost finitely many automorphisms. Which algebras are these? Can they be described another way, either with a natural condition or with equations inside of $\frak A$?

Comment: When $B$ is not an integral domain there is $B=\prod_{n\ge 1} \Bbb{Q}$, $B'=B[x]/(x^2+1)$ which has no nilpotents, if $a_n = \pm 1$ then $x\mapsto ax$ is in $Aut(B'/B)$.

Comment: @M.G. Yes sorry. I should have said that if $B$ is a finite commutative $k$-algebra of characteristic $0$ then it is $=\prod_\mathfrak{m} B_\mathfrak{m}$, with Hensel lemma the residue field $\kappa(\mathfrak{m})=B_\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}$ is a subring of $B_\mathfrak{m}$ so $B_\mathfrak{m}=\kappa(\mathfrak{m})\oplus Nil(B_\mathfrak{m})$ and $B=(\prod_\mathfrak{m}\kappa(\mathfrak{m}))\oplus Nil(B)$ which has infinitely many $k$-automorphisms iff $Nil(B)$ is non-zero.

Comment: @reuns: Ah, thanks, I see. I've now deleted my comment too since it's no longer relevant.